# csv dictionary does not reset to the beginning when looping through it multiple times

Tags: python, csv

I am looping a CSV file, which is opened as dictionary. The problem is that while I loop through the rows in the dictionary, the main `for` loop goes to the next item. The dictionary does not reset to the first item when running the `for` loop. So if it gets to the last row, it doesn't change.

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
source1_csv = open("output.csv", mode='r')
dictionary_csv = csv.DictReader(source1_csv)

for letters in names:
    for entry in dictionary_csv:
        print(entry["name"])
        if entry['name'] == letters:
            print("found it")
```

You can use any CSV file, just replace the key in the `entry`, and notice that if there is no match on the outer `for` loop, once that the next item in the `names` is selected, the inner for loop for the dictionary will just exit because the dictionary is already on the last position and does not reset.

How do I avoid this, so the position of the dictionary is reset and parse through every row for every entry of the names list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**:

From your code above, it doesn't look like that you need to iterate over the entire csv multiple times, you can just switch the loops like:

```
for entry in dictionary_csv:
    for letters in names:
        print(entry["name"])
        if entry['name'] == letters:
            print("found it")
```

Switching the loop over `dictionary_csv` to outer loop will avoid looping over csv multiple times.

**Solution 2**:

But if you don't want to change the order of loops, you can simply convert the `DictReader` to `list` before consuming it yourself. This way, `list` will consume the reader, and return you a list of it, and you can iterate over it multiple times:

```
dictionary_csv = list(csv.DictReader(source1_csv))
```

But if your csv is rather big, creating a list out of it isn't recommended, as list size will be big.

**Solution 3**:

Instead of creating a list, you can also seek the source file `source1_csv` to 0 before the inner loop:

```
for letters in names:
    source1_csv.seek(0)
    for entry in dictionary_csv:
        print(entry["name"])
        if entry['name'] == letters:
            print("found it")
```

It will take the source file to the start, and `dictionary_csv` will read it again for you.

*Edit*:

As @merlyn pointed out in below comments, that the solution 3 will not work entirely correctly, because after seeking to 0, `dictionary_csv` will interpret the first line of the csv (headers) as a separate data row. So, you'll have to ignore a line after seeking to 0.

```
source1_csv.seek(0)
source1_csv.readline()
```

Or, re-instantiate `dictionary_csv` everytime you seek `source1_csv` (For that, you can see @merlyn's answer below).

Comment: Thanks! It works once I cast it as list. Is there a way to iterate or reset the "index pointer" of the dictionary? Just curious to know if there is a way to do so.

Comment: Yes, there is a way, you'll actually have to seek `source1_csv` to 0, and `DictReader` will read it again for you.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad There's a small bug in solution 3. If dictionary_csv is not re-instantiated every time you seek the start of the file, it will interpret the headers of the csv file as regular entries.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out. I didn't notice it before. Let me just correct it.

Comment: @merlyn Corrected. Thanks. You were right about `dictionary_csv` taking the row of headers as a separate data row, but instead of re-instantiating it, another variant could be to ignore the first line.

Answer (score 1):

`csv` doesn't provide a way to reset the iterator but the file object interface does. You can reset a file to it's starting position using `file.seek(0)`.

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
source1_csv = open("output.csv", mode='r')

for letters in names:
    source1_csv.seek(0)
    for entry in csv.DictReader(source1_csv):
        print(entry["name"])
        if entry['name'] == letters:
            print("found it")
```

Of course, you can also store the entries in a list and iterate on the as many time as you want. But that won't with files too large to store in memory.